# css body direction rtl issue

Tags: html, css, frontend

well I want to make a billingual webpage so I made two stylesheets one rtl.css and another ltr.css and I have rtl stylesheet linked to my html..it's linked properly I tried changing the background color and it changes...
so the problem is when I try the code below it doesnt work at all..its still ltr

```
:root{direction:rtl;}
```

I even tried :

```
body{direction:rtl}
html{direction:rtl}
```

I tried specifying "unicode-bidi:override;"and embed
and none helped

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ```direction: rtl``` should do the trick for you. Perhaps, the problem lies somewhere within the section that your're linking style sheets on the right page. It's difficult to say because you haven't provided us with your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on multiple CSS files to provide different layouts of the same style is a bad practice. So, since your question isn't that clear, I'll try to help to get rid of the whole problem.
Firstly, you should include a single stylesheet that considers the differences in specific components based on a static attribute. For example, set an attribute of the `html` tag called `layout-dir` along with the `lang` attribute.

```html
<html lang="en" layout-dir="ltr">
...
</html>
```

Whether you're using PHP, ASP.NET, React.js, etc. both these attributes must change whenever the displaying language changes. That being said, we'll style based on the `layout-dir`. For example, consider the following code:

**HTML**

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">...</div>
    <div class="child">...</div>
    <div class="child">...</div>
    <div class="child">...</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.child {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Now, when the layout direction is ltr we want the children divs to render starting from the left; otherwise, from the right. So, we say:

```css
html[layout-dir="ltr"] #parent {
    flex-direction: row;
}

html[layout-dir="rtl"] #parent {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Back to the attributes in the `html` tag, you may set the `layout-dir` like this:

**PHP**

```php
<?php
<html lang="<?=$lang?>" layout-dir="<?=$dir?>">
...
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```js
const html = document.getElementByTagName("html");
html.setAttribute("lang", "en");
html.setAttribute("layout-dir", "ltr");
```